# Angular Typescript How to detect URL change on new window?

Tags: angular, angular6

I am using the latest angular 6. I need to open a new window with a URL based on user inputs. The URL has a return URL specified.
Once the return URL is fully loaded , I need to access the DOM and extract an element out of it.

To begin with in my service I have below code

```
getNativeWindow() {
  return window;
}
```

The service has been injected into a component which as function like below

```
onSubmitAuthDetails() {
  console.log('onSubmitAuthDetails');
  this.nativeWindow = this.loginService.getNativeWindow();
  var newWindow = this.nativeWindow.open(this.userInput +
     '/Login?returnUrl=//AppLaunch&ia=1');
  newWindow.popstate = function (event) {
     console.log('event triggered', event);
  };
  console.log('Window opened done-');
}
```

The new window comes up in a new window and based on the workflow , it eventually loads the AppLaunch page.
However I am not able to figure out the event which will capture this ?
popstate doesn't work.

Is there some other way or some other event I must listen to ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of CORS probably. Since the originator is different from the new URL launched.